# Initialize a Python dictionnary with another dictionnary

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to initialise a dictionary and always assign an empty data structure to each key which are then later used.

This is the result and behaviour I would like:

```
data = {
    "record" : {
        "fields_array" : [],
        "df" : pd.DataFrame(),
        "df_fields" : pd.DataFrame(columns = ["name", "units", "field_type", "base_type", "type"]),
        "rows" : []
    },
    "device_info" : {
        "fields_array" : [],
        "df" : pd.DataFrame(),
        "df_fields" : pd.DataFrame(columns = ["name", "units", "field_type", "base_type", "type"]),
        "rows" : []
    },
}
```

So each key refers to an unique DataFrame or array.

I wanted to simply my code like this:

```
data_struct = {  
        "fields_array" : [],
        "df" : pd.DataFrame(),
        "df_fields" : pd.DataFrame(columns = ["name", "units", "field_type", "base_type", "type"]),
        "rows" : []
}

data = {
    "record" : data_struct,
    "device_info" : data_struct,
}
```

However, if I now use `data["record"]["df"]` or `data["device_info"]["df"]`, they refer to the same DataFrame.

Why is this behaviour and how can I solve this problem? I have to add many more keys to the `data` dictionary.

Comment: "Why is this behaviour" because the `"record"` and `"devide_info"` keys are both associated with the **same object**, the one being referred to by `data_struct`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html?highlight=deepcopy#copy.deepcopy)

```
data = {
    "record" : deepcopy(data_struct),
    "device_info" : deepcopy(data_struct),
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
data = defaultdict(lambda: {  
    "fields_array" : [],
    "df" : pd.DataFrame(),
    "df_fields" : pd.DataFrame(columns = ["name", "units", "field_type", "base_type", "type"]),
    "rows" : []
})
```

And then just access any keys:

```
data['record']
data['device_info']
```